# Creating attribute field with restricted values on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, boolean

I am looking to create a field in my attribute table for polyline features and I want the values for the field to be restricted to specified options (that is, a field with just YES/NO value). 
Any ideas on how I can do that on arcgis 10.2?

Answer (score 1):

Boolean attributes are not possible, but you can simulate it by assigning a domain to you attribute. Check out the [ESRI help on domains](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001s00000001000000), you want to use a [coded-value domain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Creating_a_new_coded_value_domain/001s00000004000000/).